# How to Select continuous date in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any function to check for continuous date. I'm having problem on working with this issue below:

My table has a `datetime` column with the following data:

```
----------
2015-03-11
2015-03-12
2015-03-13
2015-03-16
```

Given start date as `2015-3-11` and end date  as `2015-3-17`. I want the result as:

```
----------
2015-03-11
2015-03-12
2015-03-13
```

Can anyone suggest anything ?

Comment: What is type of your field?

Comment: I just edited my question in the end date. now you can see that i cannot apply the in or between option now.

Comment: What if there is no `2015-03-11` in the data? And one day skip, but the next two or three dates are continuous?

Comment: Which version of MSSQL do you use?

Comment: it will only start from the given start date,if there is no continuous value from the start date then it could show null. but it will not take any continuous values thats not started from the start date. and its sql 2005

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm thinking this is somewhat a variation of **[Grouping Islands of Contiguous Dates](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/71550/)** problem. This can be done using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c67a0/6/0)

```
CREATE TABLE Test(
    tDate   DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO Test VALUES
('20150311'), ('20150312'), ('20150313'), ('20150316');

DECLARE @startDate  DATE = '20150311'
DECLARE @endDate    DATE = '20150317'

;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT
        *,
        RN = DATEADD(DD, - (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY tDATE) - 1), tDate)
    FROM Test
    WHERE 
        tDate >= @startDate
        AND tDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @endDate)
)
SELECT CAST(tDate AS DATE)
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = @startDate
```

**RESULT**

```
|------------|
| 2015-03-11 |
| 2015-03-12 |
| 2015-03-13 |
```

---

Here is the SQL Server 2005 version:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/17eaa/2/0)

```
DECLARE @startDate  DATETIME
DECLARE @endDate    DATETIME

SET @startDate  = '20150311'
SET @endDate    = '20150317'

;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT
        *,
        RN = DATEADD(DD, -(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY tDATE)-1), tDate)
    FROM Test
    WHERE 
        tDate >= @startDate
        AND tDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @endDate)
)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), tDate, 121)
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = @startDate
```

Comment: In your code everything works well.but for end date it seems have some issue. like if the start date is '20150311' and end date is '20150312' then it shows result 2015-03-11  2015-03-12  2015-03-13 . But it should be 2015-03-11  2015-03-12

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. It should be `tdate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @endDate)` instead of `@endDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @endDate)`. See my edit.

Comment: @GinUchiha, no problem. Gald I could help.

Answer (score 3):

For `MSSQL 2012`. This will return MAX continuous groups:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(d DATE)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('20150311'),
('20150312'),
('20150313'),
('20150316')


;WITH
c1 AS(SELECT d, IIF(DATEDIFF(dd,LAG(d, 1, DATEADD(dd, -1, d)) OVER(ORDER BY d), d) = 1, 0, 1) AS n FROM @t),
c2 AS(SELECT d, SUM(n) OVER(ORDER BY d) AS n FROM c1) 

SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES MIN(d) AS StartDate, MAX(d) AS EndDate, COUNT(*) AS DayCount
FROM c2
GROUP BY n
ORDER BY DayCount desc
```

Output:

```
StartDate   EndDate     DayCount
2015-03-11  2015-03-13  3
```

For

```
('20150311'),
('20150312'),
('20150313'),
('20150316'),
('20150317'),
('20150318'),
('20150319'),
('20150320')
```

Output:

```
StartDate   EndDate     DayCount
2015-03-16  2015-03-20  5
```

Apply filtering in `c1 CTE`:

```
c1 AS(SELECT d, IIF(DATEDIFF(dd,LAG(d, 1, DATEADD(dd, -1, d)) OVER(ORDER BY d), d) = 1, 0, 1) AS n FROM @t WHERE d BETWEEN '20150311' AND '20150320'),
```

For `MSSQL 2008`:

```
;WITH
c1 AS(SELECT d, (SELECT MAX(d) FROM @t it WHERE it.d < ot.d) AS pd FROM @t ot),
c2 AS(SELECT d, CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd,ISNULL(pd, DATEADD(dd, -1, d)),  d) = 1 THEN  0 ELSE 1 END AS n FROM c1),
c3 AS(SELECT d, (SELECT SUM(n) FROM c2 ci WHERE ci.d <= co.d)  AS n FROM c2 co) 

SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES MIN(d) AS StartDate, MAX(d) AS EndDate, COUNT(*) AS DayCount
FROM c3
GROUP BY n
ORDER BY DayCount desc
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to declare any start date or end date as other answers says, you need a `row_num` with `datediff` function:

```
create table DateFragTest (cDate date);
insert into DateFragTest 
       values ('2015-3-11'),
              ('2015-3-12'),
              ('2015-3-13'),
              ('2015-3-16')

   with cte as 
      (select 
        cDate,
        row_number() over (order by cDate ) as rn
       from
        DateFragTest)
    select cDate 
    from cte t1  
    where datediff(day,
                   (select cDate from cte t2 where t2.rn=t1.rn+1),
                   t1.cDate)<>1
```

**Output:**

```
cDate
2015-03-11
2015-03-12
2015-03-13
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/acc29/1)

Answer (score 1):

For `sql server 2012`-

```
WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT [datex]
    ,      lead([datex]) OVER ( ORDER BY [datex]) lead_datex
    ,      datediff(dd,[datex],lead([datex]) OVER ( ORDER BY [datex]) ) AS diff
    FROM [dbo].[datex]
)
SELECT c.[datex]
FROM [cte] AS c
WHERE diff >=1
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Use `BETWEEN`

The query will go like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table_name
WHERE your_date_column_name BETWEEN '2015-3-11' AND '2015-3-13'
```

Answer (score -2):

`(dt between x and y)` or just `(dt >= x and dt <= y)`.