# How to select the continuous data from sqlite file

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, linq

I have some data in SQLite files, and want to manipulate it from C#.

The data includes three columns, `Time`, `Temperature` and `Power`. And I want to find the groups of records which have a `Temperature` higher than 30, and last more than 3 minutes, and calculate the mean of power of each group (continuous time range).

[Select continuous ranges from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213455/select-continuous-ranges-from-table)

[How to Select continuous date in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29339563/how-to-select-continuous-date-in-sql)

I find two answers above, but can't reach the answer of mine.

It can be get the results directly with a SQL string (for SQLiteDataAdapter). or select all data and manipulate it with c# (datatable.Select,Computer, or LINQ).

```
| No   | Time              | Temp | Power |
| ---- | ----------------- | ---- | ----- |
| 1    | 2019-11-4 0:00:00 | 25   | 1200  |
| 2    | 2019-11-4 0:01:10 | 30   | 1000  |
| 3    | 2019-11-4 0:02:20 | 31   | 680   |
| 4    | 2019-11-4 0:03:30 | 34   | 960   |
| 5    | 2019-11-4 0:04:40 | 29   | 800   |
| 6    | 2019-11-4 0:05:50 | 31   | 600   |
| 7    | 2019-11-4 0:07:00 | 32   | 400   |
| 8    | 2019-11-4 0:08:10 | 33   | 900   |
| 9    | 2019-11-4 0:09:20 | 34   | 1000  |
| 10   | 2019-11-4 0:10:30 | 39   | 200   |
| 11   | 2019-11-4 0:11:40 | 24   | 350   |
```

Expected results: select the continuous records when `Temp` more than 30 and continuous time more than 3 minutes as a group, and calculate the mean of `Power`.

One group in the example table including No from 6 to 10. And the mean is 620.

---

Thanks to all.The codes used in my works:

```
        string sql = "WITH CTE AS (" +
                     "SELECT(Temp > 30) AS tempgt30,Time, Power," +
                            "ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY No) rn," +
                            "ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY(Temp > 30) ORDER BY No) rn2" +
                     " FROM data" +
                     ")" +
                    " SELECT MIN(rn)AS minrow,MAX(rn) as maxrow," +
                            "strftime('%s', MAX(Time)) - strftime('%s', MIN(Time)) AS duration," +
                            "AVG(Power) AS mean" +
                    " FROM CTE" +
                    " WHERE tempgt30" +
                    " GROUP BY(rn2 - rn)" +
                    " HAVING duration > 180;";

        con.Open();

        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            using (SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, con))
            {
                dataAdapter.Fill(datatable);
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were looking at the correct questions as this is indeed a gaps and islands problem. In your case the "islands" are the readings where `Temp > 30`. We can form them and calculate the mean `Power` and duration of the island (in seconds) using this query:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT (Temp > 30) AS tempgt30, 
       Time,
       Power,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY No) rn,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY (Temp > 30) ORDER BY No) rn2
FROM data
)
SELECT MIN(rn) AS minrow, 
       MAX(rn) as maxrow, 
       MIN(Time) AS start,
       MAX(Time) AS end,
       strftime('%s', MAX(Time)) - strftime('%s', MIN(Time)) AS duration,
       AVG(Power) AS mean
FROM CTE
WHERE tempgt30
GROUP BY (rn2 - rn)
HAVING duration > 180
```

Output:

```
minrow  maxrow  start                   end                     duration    mean
6       10      2019-11-04 00:05:50     2019-11-04 00:10:30     280         620
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sWWV9x2n65Wn8TSjWirpnF/1)

Comment: the problem with this is 3-4 didnt run more than 3 mins

Comment: `MAX(Time) OVER (PARTITION BY Time AND (Temp > 30) ORDER BY No) maxTime,` is easy enough to add to the `CLE` (along with min).. but I have no idea how to handle DateDiff and comparisons in SqlLite (though I think `SQLiteDataAdapter` is probably an aspect of that`

Comment: @GabrielLlorico I have added a check for the duration of the period being longer than 3 minutes.

Comment: @BrettCaswell  you can use `strftime('%s', date)` to get a unix timestamp

Comment: thanks.. your solution is quite good here.. is `MIN(Time)` the same as `Time` in the select from `CTE`?  I realized after my comment above that `minTime` based on partitioning was not going to work continuously.

Comment: @BrettCaswell no - if you were to `SELECT * FROM CTE` it has all the rows from the original table in it. So you need to get `MIN(Time)` while grouping over the island number.

Answer (score 1):

I recommand nick's answer.

and below script is sql server version :

you can use `temptable + cursor` to do it.

logic :

- select into to create temptable and filter `Temp > 30`
- lag function get PreviousNo
- run corsor to check if `PreviousNo = CurrentNo - 1` then put into same group
- group having time minutes diff > 3 to get data;

> ```
> CREATE TABLE T
>   ([No] int, [Time] datetime, [Temp] int, [Power] int)
> ;
>
> INSERT INTO T
>   ([No], [Time], [Temp], [Power])
> VALUES
>   (1, '2019-11-04 00:00:00', 25, 1200),
>   (2, '2019-11-04 00:01:10', 30, 1000),
>   (3, '2019-11-04 00:02:20', 31, 680),
>   (4, '2019-11-04 00:03:30', 34, 960),
>   (5, '2019-11-04 00:04:40', 29, 800),
>   (6, '2019-11-04 00:05:50', 31, 600),
>   (7, '2019-11-04 00:07:00', 32, 400),
>   (8, '2019-11-04 00:08:10', 33, 900),
>   (9, '2019-11-04 00:09:20', 34, 1000),
>   (10, '2019-11-04 00:10:30', 39, 200),
>   (11, '2019-11-04 00:11:40', 24, 350)
> ;
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 11 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> with cte as (
>   select 
>    LAG(No, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY No) AS PreviousNo,
>    null AS GroupId,
>    *
>   from T
>   where Temp > 30 
> )
> select * into #T from cte;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 7 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select * from #T
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> PreviousNo | GroupId | No | Time                | Temp | Power
> ---------: | ------: | -: | :------------------ | ---: | ----:
>          0 |    null |  3 | 04/11/2019 00:02:20 |   31 |   680
>          3 |    null |  4 | 04/11/2019 00:03:30 |   34 |   960
>          4 |    null |  6 | 04/11/2019 00:05:50 |   31 |   600
>          6 |    null |  7 | 04/11/2019 00:07:00 |   32 |   400
>          7 |    null |  8 | 04/11/2019 00:08:10 |   33 |   900
>          8 |    null |  9 | 04/11/2019 00:09:20 |   34 |  1000
>          9 |    null | 10 | 04/11/2019 00:10:30 |   39 |   200
> ```

> ```
> DECLARE @tmp_no int,@groupId int = 1;
>
> DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR 
>   LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
> FOR 
> SELECT No 
> FROM #T
>
> OPEN MY_CURSOR
> FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @tmp_no
> WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
> BEGIN 
>     if not (( select PreviousNo from #T where No = @tmp_no ) = @tmp_no - 1)  begin
>        set @groupId = @groupId + 1;
>     end
>     update #T set groupId = @groupId where no = @tmp_no;
>     FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @tmp_no
> END
> CLOSE MY_CURSOR
> DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 7 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select * from #T
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> PreviousNo | GroupId | No | Time                | Temp | Power
> ---------: | ------: | -: | :------------------ | ---: | ----:
>          0 |       2 |  3 | 04/11/2019 00:02:20 |   31 |   680
>          3 |       2 |  4 | 04/11/2019 00:03:30 |   34 |   960
>          4 |       3 |  6 | 04/11/2019 00:05:50 |   31 |   600
>          6 |       3 |  7 | 04/11/2019 00:07:00 |   32 |   400
>          7 |       3 |  8 | 04/11/2019 00:08:10 |   33 |   900
>          8 |       3 |  9 | 04/11/2019 00:09:20 |   34 |  1000
>          9 |       3 | 10 | 04/11/2019 00:10:30 |   39 |   200
> ```

> ```
> select 
>    convert(varchar(3),min(no)) + ' to ' + convert(varchar(3),max(no)) as no_range
>    ,avg(power) as avgpower
>    ,min(Time) as mintime
>    ,max(Time) as maxtime
>    , datediff(minute,min(Time),max(Time)) timediff
> from #T
> group by groupid having datediff(minute,min(Time),max(Time)) > 3
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> no_range | avgpower | mintime             | maxtime             | timediff
> :------- | -------: | :------------------ | :------------------ | -------:
> 6 to 10  |      620 | 04/11/2019 00:05:50 | 04/11/2019 00:10:30 |        5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7e4b5c5c93d619191724587c0786d40c)*

Comment: A lot of this answer is not valid for SQLite